# Magento 2 : How to merge JS for frontend?

Tags: magento2, javascript

I want to merge all `js` request and for this I am using `Merge JavaScript` setting of Magento and set it to yes.

But still lots off `js` request in browser which are not merged.

How do I merge all these request ?